# How to share writeble stores on Sveltekit routes?

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit, svelte-store

I'm new to Sveltekit and I'm trying to share a writeable store I've created among different routes.

**src/stores.js**

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const users = writable([]);
```

When my application starts I'm able to update my store on the `src/routes/+page.svelte` default route by doing something like that:

**src/routes/+page.svelte**

```js
<script>
    import { users } from './stores.js';

    function addUser() {
        users.update(list => [...list, `user-${list.length}`]);
    }
</script>

<button on:click={addUser}>Add User</button>
```

**My question is** How do retrieve the `users` stores on a different route? For example on my `src/routes/users/+page.svelte` route? I've tried the below but it doesn't work.

**src/routes/mylist/+page.svelte**

```js
<script>
  import { users } from "../../stores";
</script>

<div>
<h1>Users List</h1>
<ul>
  {#each $users as user}
   <li>{user}</li>
  {/each}
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This should work. Is the import path in src/routes/mylist/+page.svelte correct?